# Añadir propiedad "add" a un formulario en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo un formulario en Django 1.11 con un campo models.ForeignKey del modelo que representa. Dicho campo en el sitio de administración de Django me permite, bien escoger un registro de una lista, o añadir (con la típica cruz verde que abre otro formulario) un registro nuevo del modelo asociado.

Al representar ese formulario fuera del sitio de administración todo es similar excepto los campos model.ForeingKey and model.ManyToManyField, que solo me aparece la lista con los registros ya añadidos, pero no la posibilidad de añadir otro nuevo con la cruz verde asociado a ese campo. Espero haberme explicado.
¿Hay alguna forma de permitir añadir esa función para que se muestre en el formulario?. Gracias de antemano.

El form lo represento así:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table><br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-
      primary"  value="Confirmar">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Reformulo la pregunta.
¿Como puedo añadir el widget seleccionado para que se muestre en un formulario que no sea el sitio de administración? Hasta ahora solo consigo mostrar la lista desplegable, pero no puedo añadir ningún registro nuevo que no esté en la misma.

[image: Imagen de formulario]

Answer (score 0):

Puedas seguir este tutorial [Replicating Django’s admin form pop-ups](http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/replicating-djangos-admin/) para replicar esa funcionalidad del Django Admin, la repliqué hace un par de años y funcionó a la perfección

Puedes luego hacer ajustes según tus necesidades, debes tener muy presente que el `id` del botón que lance la nueva ventana para crear el registro debe estar compuesto por la palabra add y el id del elemento (combobox por lo general, en tu caso debe ser algo como `add_id_question`) donde se cargará el registro recién creado, este comentario está mencionado allí también, pero muchas veces pasa desapercibido

Espero sea de tu ayuda

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y el enlace. Viendo la fecha del artículo podría parecer que está algo desactualizado pero si dices que lo replicaste hace un par de años... aunque me desconcierta el archivo javascript RelatedObjectLookups.js. Estoy usando la versión 1.11 de Django.

Comment: @Kalasni Si en efecto, aunque el tutorial es de viaja data, los pasos y la funcionalidad siguen vigente (basados en la funcionalidad que da django Admin) - lo aplique hace par de años, lo sigo aplicando y funciona. Para acceder al archivo `RelatedObjectLookups.js` simplemente puedes hacer una copia de la carpeta de estáticos de la app admin de django (django/contrib/admin/static/admin), en la carpeta de `static` de tu proyecto

Comment: ¿puedo copiar a la carpeta static de mi proyecto sólo el archivo RelatedObjectLookups.js, o debería copiar ...admin//static/admin/ al completo?. ¡Gracias de nuevo! @angel-f

Comment: @Kalasni pues fíjate que yo le copié completo, sin embargo creo copiando solo el archivo debería funcionar, pues no recuerdo alguna dependencia con algún otro file, pruébalo así y me comentas que tal